# Stack same screen multiple times with React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have 3 screen on a *StackNavigator* : `MainSearch`, `MonsterPage`, `ItemPage`.
And I want to stack `MonsterPage` and `ItemPage` multiple times ***(from `MonsterPage` you can go to `ItemPage` and vice versa)***

Is possible to instantiate the screens?

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: MainSearch,
        MonsterPage: MonsterPage,
        ItemPage: ItemPage
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home"
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**What I want:**

> MainSearch -> ItemPage(1) -> MonsterPage(1) -> ItemPage(2) -> etc...

or

> MainSearch -> MonsterPage(1) -> ItemPage(1) -> MonsterPage(2) -> etc...

**What I get:**

> MainSearch -> MonsterPage(1) -> ItemPage(1) ->(goes back to) MonsterPage(1)
>
> [Gif showing what happens](https://i.imgur.com/IQiQvXz.gif)

**MainSearch**

```js
onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate(`${r._source.super_cat === 'monster' ? 'MonsterPage' : 'ItemPage'}`, { item: r._source }) }}
```

**MonsterPage**

```js
onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('ItemPage', { item: {id: drop.item_id, NameZh_ragmobile: drop.item_name_EN, super_cat: 'item'} }) }
```

**ItemPage**

```js
onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('MonsterPage', { item: {id: mob.mob_id, NameZh_ragmobile: mob.mob_name_EN, super_cat: 'monster'} }) }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it... just change `this.props.navigation.navigate(...)` to `this.props.navigation.push(...)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, maybe check your import path too so that you are not pointing to the same screen multiple times like shown below.

```
import CategoriesScreen from './screens/CategoriesScreen'   <--- Same
import MealsScreen from './screens/CategoriesScreen'        <--- Path
```